How can i add searching to an Antd grid in reactjs?
I have the following:
    <div>
<Card title="Names" bordered={false} style={{ width: '100%' }} headStyle={{  backgroundColor: '#EFEFEF' }}>

    <TableAnt dataSource={product.names} columns={columns}
     
        pagination={{ defaultPageSize: 5, showSizeChanger: true, pageSizeOptions:   ['10', '20', '30'] }}
    />
</Card>

and i have columns defined as
    const columns = [
 {
     title: 'FirstName',
     dataIndex: 'firstname',
     key: 'firstname',           
 },
 {
     title: 'LastName',
     dataIndex: 'lastName',
     key: 'lastname',
 },
 {
     title: 'Address',
     dataIndex: 'address',
     key: 'address',
 },
 {
     title: 'City',
     dataIndex: 'city',
     key: 'city',
 },
 

];
I have tried adding the key word Searchable in the columns , but that did not work .
How can i make the Antd Design grid searchabel by FirstName , lastname or whatever i decide ?
